# Python 3.5 Youtube API search by keyword: SyntaxError in except block

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api

I'm trying to get data with YouTube API with the following code that Youtube releases. I also added my personal API key and the parentheses at `print`, but the code doesn't work. When I try to run it in PyCharm, I get:

```
except HttpError, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and I don't understand why.
Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser


# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = "MY_API_KEY"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  videos = []
  channels = []
  playlists = []

  # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
  # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                 search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#channel":
      channels.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                   search_result["id"]["channelId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#playlist":
      playlists.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                    search_result["id"]["playlistId"]))

  print ("Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n")
  print ("Channels:\n", "\n".join(channels), "\n")
  print ("Playlists:\n", "\n".join(playlists), "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default="Rome")
  argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
  args = argparser.parse_args()

  try:
    youtube_search(args)
  except HttpError, e:
    print ("An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code was written for python 2 and while you converted `print` to a function (which is necessary for python 3) you forgot to convert the `except` block:

`except HttpError as e:` is the python 3 way of doing exceptions but you could also use `except e:` which will except all exceptions (might not be what you want).

Also, you can read more about the changes between python 2 and 3 [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#handling-exceptions). Some might surprise you!

Comment: It's worth noting that the Python3 syntax is still valid in Python2, so it should be preferred even in Python2 code.